# Как удалить динамический элемент?

Tags: javascript

Есть форма для динамического добавления картинок

```
<form action="uploads" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="uploads_files">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/*"/>
</div>
```

Скрипт добавления

```
(function(){
if(!window.File || !window.FileList || !window.FileReader)
    return console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
document.getElementById("uploads_files").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var clone = event.target.cloneNode(),
        files = event.target.files,
        output = document.getElementById("result");
    clone.value=null;
    this.appendChild(clone);
    this.focus();
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if(!file.type.match('image'))
            continue;
        var picReader = new FileReader();
        picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
            var picFile = event.target;
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = 'preview';
            div.innerHTML = "<button type='button' href='' class='del_img'>Удалить</button><img class='thumbnail' src='"
                + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
            output.insertBefore(div, null);
        });
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }    });})();
```

Скрипт удаления

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_img', function() {
    $(this).parents("div:first").remove();
});
```

Добавление и удаление происходят нормально. Но, только в браузере.
Например, выбрал юзер 6 картинок. Потом посмотрел и 2 удалил. Визуально они удалились, но в контроллер передаются все равно 6 штук.
Я в JS не силен, помогите, кто знает.

Comment: А есть код который отправляет данные? Или у вас просто кнопка submit ?

Comment: Именно так. Обычная форма. До отправки еще дело не дошло. Результат я смотрел в браузере с помощью var_dump()

Comment: Вот тема где это обсуждается: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist. Если кратко, то удалить файлы из формы нормально нельзя, так как поля там только для чтения. Можно разными хаками, но могут быть вопросы по кроссбраузерности. Адекватно можно удалить только все файлы сразу.